# Chartjs, Bubble Chart, positioning problem with duplicate value in data labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bubble-chart

With a duplicate value in the data labels - Is there a way to draw the bubble on the first or second duplicate value in the bubble chart?

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var options = {responsive: true, 
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
};

var mixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["1", "2", "1", "4"], //Same Value on First and Third Position
      datasets: [
        //Lines
        {
          label: "First_Line",
          type: "line",
          borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
          data: [5,10,7,12],
          fill: false
        }, {
          label: "Second_Line",
          type: "line",
          borderColor: "#3e95cd",
          data: [1,4,15,6],
          fill: false
        }, 
        //Bubbles
        {
          label: "Bubble_One",
          type: "bubble",
          backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
          data: [{ x: "2", y: 10, r: 15}],
        }, 
        {
          label: "Bubble_Two",
          type: "bubble",
          backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
          backgroundColorHover: "#3e95cd",
          data: [{x: ???, y: 6, r: 15}] //First "1" or Second "1" possible?
        }
      ]
  },       
options: options   
});
</script>
```

Something like "1"[0] unfortunately does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it directly afaik but you can put an extra part in the label and filter it out of there with the callbacks for the tooltip and the axis:

```html
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        offset: false,
        ticks: {
          callback: function(val) {
            return this.getLabelForValue(val).split('-')[0]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: (ttItem) => {
            if (ttItem.dataset.type === "bubble") {
              return `${ttItem.label}: (${ttItem.raw.x.split('-')[0]},${ttItem.raw.y})`
            } else if (ttItem.dataset.type === "line") {
              return `${ttItem.dataset.label}: ${ttItem.parsed.y}`
            }
          },
          title: (ttItem) => (ttItem[0].label.split('-')[0])
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var mixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["1-1", "2", "1-2", "4"], //Same Value on First and Third Position
      datasets: [
        //Lines
        {
          label: "First_Line",
          type: "line",
          borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
          data: [5, 10, 7, 12],
          fill: false
        }, {
          label: "Second_Line",
          type: "line",
          borderColor: "#3e95cd",
          data: [1, 4, 15, 6],
          fill: false
        },
        //Bubbles
        {
          label: "Bubble_One",
          type: "bubble",
          backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
          data: [{
            x: "2",
            y: 10,
            r: 15
          }],
        },
        {
          label: "Bubble_Two",
          type: "bubble",
          backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
          backgroundColorHover: "#3e95cd",
          data: [{
            x: "1-2",
            y: 6,
            r: 15
          }] //First "1" or Second "1" possible?
        }
      ]
    },
    options: options
  });
</script>
```

Comment: ok thanks, if there is no other way i will try something like this